# learning about function prototypes and function overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, function-prototypes

can anyone give me an example of function overloading in c++ with 4 function prototypes ? i still don't get them quite good ..

sorry newbie question, thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: seems like homework assignment.

Comment: nope , 3 or more if can hehe. :D btw yes i have googled it but i belive stackoverflow will make me understand this faster :D .

Comment: Actually, "function prototype" is more a C term. In C++ we just say "function declaration". The C++ internaltional standard makes a clear distinction between declarations and definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are C++ function declarations and would typically be in the header (.h or .hpp) file.  These particular declarations have no code.  The code is in the definition shown further below.

```
int sum(int a, int b);
int sum(int a, int b, int c);
int sum(int a, int b, int c, int d);
int sum(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
```

The above four functions have the same name, but the C++ compiler will call the one whose parameter signature matches the one in the calling code.  The purpose of a declaration is to tell the compiler what the return type and parameter signature of a function are.  If more than one function has the same name but differs in its parameter signature, it is referred to as overloaded.  This is a C++ feature not present in C.  Note that the return type cannot be used to differentiate overloaded functions.

The following are the definitions (implementations) of the overloaded functions and would typically be in the module (.cpp or .cc or .cxx) file.  This is where the executable code resides between the braces { } that surround the function block:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return (a + b + c);
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return (a + b + c + d);
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    return (a + b + c + d + e);
}
```

Usage example:

```
std::cout << sum(3, 4, 5) << std::endl;
```

will invoke the code for the second overloaded function listed above that takes three `int` parameters.

Comment: so there are no prototypes in C++ ? olny in c ? how do we do the second one in C ? do we put them two ?

Comment: ah i understand about overflow concept ok. now its about the prototypes, im still a bit confused, so prototype = declaration ? like function x( arg1, arg2) ? is this a prototype ? what is the diffrence between normal function in c ? and in c++ ? i still just dont get it.

Comment: @Adam it's not defined in C++ what a "prototype" is. Collegially, a function prototype is a function declaration though. It's only defined in C, in which it is the information about a function parameter count and types. It's not true that `void f() { }` would not be a declaration: It's both a declaration and definition. It's important to keep this concept distinct from "signature". The signature of a function can be seen as its identity: Roughly its scope (the class or namespace it's a member of), name and type. For template functions, the signature contains further stuff.

Comment: @Amardeep your last 3 function definitions have extra `;` in them.